# I am not able to change the data type of an already existing table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (
emp_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR (20),
birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
sex VARCHAR (20),
salary INT,
super_id INT,
branch_id SMALLINT
);

ALTER TABLE Employee
ALTER COLUMN sex VARCHAR(1);
```

I am a beginner so go easy on me, please. I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong.
error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(1)' at line 2

Comment: You tagged SQL Server and MySQL here, what RDBMS are you *really* uising. The above works fine on SQL Server: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=fd2aa9b9f91b1d3fe467a1a5e33d4d33)

Comment: Is the existing data in that column wider than VARCHAR(1)?

Comment: Your syntax is fine - what does "not able to" *actually* mean?

Comment: Failed "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(1)' at line 2". This error shows up. I am using PopSQL.

Comment: YOu have T-SQL Syntax. For MySQL, it's `MODIFY COLUMN`.

Answer (score 1):

in mysql you need to use `MODIFY`

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
MODIFY COLUMN sex VARCHAR(1);
```

by the way if you already have data in your table , any value more than 1 character in sex column will be truncated , so you have to take care of that before altering column length